# print log to table or to text file on LOCAL drive

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I want to get the content of my SAS EG log into R.

My first idea was to use `PROC PRINTTO` to print to a text file that I would then import, but I can only use it to print the log to the server on which SAS is installed, which I am not able to access from R (I don't have admin rights).

I figured out a way to run egp projects from R and to read SAS tables from R however, so I will be able to fetch the log if I can redirect its content to a table, or to a macro variable that I will then store into a table.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Doesn't EG have a process step for downloading a file?

Comment: @Tom Indeed it seems like there is `PROC DOWNLOAD` http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#prcd.htm . I tried `PROC DOWNLOAD INFILE=&address_on_server OUTFILE=&local_path` but it gives me a note saying there was an error, along with a warning saying `PROC DOWNLOAD must be invoked with the RSUBMIT command.`, but this `RSUBMIT` command seems to be for communicating credentials that I probably don't have, and I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way:

- use `PROC PRINTTO` to redirect the log of my project to a file on the server where I can write to from SAS (and not R).
- read this file as a delimited file into a table, using an exotic delimiter that I will just have to try not to use in my code (no delimiter seems not to be an option unfortunately)
- import this table from R and trim the irrelevant first rows

My SAS code :

```
%let writeable_folder_on_server = /some_path/;
%let temp_log_for_R = &writeable_folder_on_server/temp_log_for_R.txt;
%let log_as_tbl = mylib.mytbl;

proc printto log="&temp_log_for_R" print="&temp_log_for_R" new;
run;

proc datasets library= mylib nolist;
delete mytbl;
run;

/* code producing log */
%put foo;
%put bar;

proc import datafile="&temp_log_for_R" out=&log_as_tbl dbms=dlm replace;
 delimiter='§';
 getnames=no;
 GUESSINGROWS=MAX;
run;
```

The replace parameter of the `IMPORT` procedure "should" make the table deletion redundant but for some reason (maybe because I used an oracle library) it doesn't.

It produces the following output, stored into the table :

```
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINTTO used (Total process time):
real time           0.01 seconds
user cpu time       0.01 seconds
system cpu time     0.01 seconds
memory              904.75k
OS Memory           15140.00k
Timestamp           01/30/2019 01:29:21 PM
Page Faults                       2
Page Reclaims                     251
Page Swaps                        0
Voluntary Context Switches        1
Involuntary Context Switches      0
Block Input Operations            0
Block Output Operations           0


28
29         proc datasets library= mylib nolist;
30         delete mytbl;
31         run;

NOTE: Deleting mylib.mytbl (memtype=DATA)
32
33         /* code producing log */
34         %put foo;
foo
35         %put bar;
bar
36

NOTE: PROCEDURE DATASETS used (Total process time)
real time           0.17 seconds
user cpu time       0.02 seconds
system cpu time     0.00 seconds
memory              2425.56k
OS Memory           17956.00k
Timestamp           01/30/2019 01:29:21 PM
2

Page Faults                       5
Page Reclaims                     858
Page Swaps                        0
Voluntary Context Switches        57
Involuntary Context Switches      4
Block Input Operations            0
Block Output Operations           0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could register and run your code as a SAS Stored Process, and use R to call it over http.  Appending `&_debug=log` will give you the log.  Just one option..  And avoids proc print.